# $\int_0^\infty 3^{-x^2} dx$ using gamma function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, gamma-function

I want to solv this problem:
$$\int_0^\infty 3^{-x^2} dx,$$
using this substitution:
$$a^{F(x)} \Longrightarrow F(x)\ln a=-t.$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Substitute $x = \sqrt {\frac{t}{{\log 3}}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/This is the definition of the gamma function:
$$ \Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt, \qquad \Re(z)>0.$$
So first let's try to make appear the exponent in the original expression to see what is needed to be done.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }3^{-x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{\ln(3^{-x^2})}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-x^2\ln(3)}dx.$$

II/Now: $t=x^2\ln(3)$ so $dx=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t\ln(3)}}$ (obviously the integration interval is the same)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-t}\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t\ln(3)}}dt=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\ln(3)}}\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\ln(3)}}\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-t}t^{1/2-1}dt\\ =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\ln(3)}}\Gamma (1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\ln(3)}}.$$

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), answering questions without context and where the OP does not show any effort is not advised.

Comment: @Gary I understand your pov but i am too a student and i understand how it can be frustating to don't find an answer. Btw, from my experience, by copying an answer if you make an effort to understand it, it really improved your understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

$3^{-x^{2}}=e^{-x^{2}\ln(3)}$

${\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{2}\ln(3)}dx}$

using this substitution:

$$x^{2}\ln(3)=t$$

$x =\sqrt {\frac{t}{{\ln(3)}}}$

$dx={\frac{1}{{2}{\sqrt{{t}{\ln(3)}}}}}dt$

${\int_0^\infty {\frac{1}{{2}{\sqrt{{t} {\ln(3)}}}}}e^{-t} dt}$

$\frac{1}{{2}{\sqrt{\ln(3)}}}{\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{-1}{2}} e^{-t} dt}$

using gamma function:

${\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{-1}{2}} e^{-t} dt}=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})={\sqrt\pi}$

so

$$\frac{1}{{2}{\sqrt{\ln(3)}}}{\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{-1}{2}} e^{-t} dt}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{{2}{\sqrt{\ln(3)}}}$$

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), answering questions without context and where the OP does not show any effort is not advised.